# Where did I make a mistake in expanding the determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to work on the left determinant to find the last one. I did as follows but, the machinery way resulted it $(+2/b)$ while I got $(-2/b)$ as coefficient. May I ask you what is my probable mistake? Thank you!

$$\begin{vmatrix}
b+a&1&0 \\ -b-1&-1&-2a \\-a-b&-1&2b
\end{vmatrix}=(1/b)\begin{vmatrix}
b+a&b&0 \\ -b-1&-b&-2a \\-a-b&-b&2b
\end{vmatrix}=(-2/b)\begin{vmatrix}
b+a&b&0 \\ b+1&+b&a \\-a-b&-b&b
\end{vmatrix}=$$

$$(-2/b)\begin{vmatrix}
-a&b&0 \\ -1&+b&a \\a&-b&b
\end{vmatrix}$$‎

Comment: In final step subtract 2nd column from 1st and write that. Otherwise sign will change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end you should multiply again by $-1$ taking $2/b$ in front.

Comment: Oh. Indeed, at the end, I did $-C_1+C_2$ and put it in $C_1$. Wasn't it an elementary operation so the sign would not be changed?

Comment: No it change since you are multiplying C1 by -1.

Comment: You can consider also that the operation is equivalent to C1-C2 in column 1 and then reversing the sign of C1.

Comment: Thanks for your time!

Comment: You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 2):

In the last passage you summed the second column to the first one and then multiplied the first one by $-1$ (or, in other words, you substituted $C_1\to -C_1-C_2$) but you did not update the coefficient accordingly.